# WOFF matching regex

Tags: regex, woff

I am trying to validate each of the font names in a WOFF link such as

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro:400,700italic,400italic,700|Radley:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

by using the following bit of code

```
<?php
$woff = 'Oswald:400,600,700Italic';
$f = preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9+]{1,20}):{0,1}(([1-9]00(italic){0,1},{0,1}){0,3})/',$woff);
echo ($f);
?>
```

which does the job pretty well.  However, I am by no means a RegEx expert so I suspect that my regex is a pretty naive one.  Any help with polishing it up would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the possible variations of valid fonts?

Comment: You should go back to questions [such as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437785/css3-element-width-in-jquery) and select the answer that worked.

Comment: I cannot be absolutely certain  but from all the testing I did the most generic format is `word+word+word:n00italic`. Needless to say, the simplest format is `fontName`,e.g. Oswald. When the font name has spaces you get the + (blame HTML for that) and the :n00italic bit is the way Google identifies font weight and decoration variants. When there are multiple variants on the same font they are  specified in the bit after the colon as a comma delimited string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching `Anonymous+Pro:400,700italic,400italic,700` with this regex:

```
/([^:]+) *: *((?:[\d\w]+,*)+)/
```

Returns:

```
> test.match(/([^:]+) *: *((?:[\d\w]+,*)+)/)
[ 'Anonymous+Pro:400,700italic,400italic,700',
  'Anonymous+Pro',
  '400,700italic,400italic,700',
  index: 0,
  input: 'Anonymous+Pro:400,700italic,400italic,700' ]
```

Would be helpful to see what you're expecting the output to be.

Comment: Thank you.  This sounds useful.  I'll need to study it before deciding if it is the right thing for the job.

Comment: Useful but the issue that you run into is that it will accept something like Anonymous+Pro:400,700italic... or indeed any other text.